# macOS Sierra : dd to USB is very slow and can't seem to use /dev/rdisk

Tags: command-line, usb, macos

**(txs all for your help and suggestions, but suspending this for now while I track down my formatting errors on that SD.  If I can't get that to work, little reason to expect `dd` to work, even if other people have encountered similar issues doing this on osx).**

I'm trying, as root, to write to micro SD to load up a Raspberry Pi's Linux:

`W$dd bs=1m if=/Users/jluc/Downloads/2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/disk2`

This is supremely slow, it's been running for 8-9 hours and hasn't written much when I kill -9 it.

`301989888 bytes transferred in 23103.442503 secs (13071 bytes/sec)`

Now, in such write ups as [Solution: dd too slow on Mac OS X](http://daoyuan.li/solution-dd-too-slow-on-mac-os-x/), he advises to use **/dev/rdisk**, because it's treated differently.

But every time I've used **/rdiskN** instead of **/diskN**, I get:

`dd: /dev/rdisk2: Input/output error`

This is on Sierra, but it worked on Yosemite, if I recall correctly.

[INSTALLING OPERATING SYSTEM IMAGES ON MAC OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md) mentions the possibility that /rdisk won't work and advises you to use /disk instead.

What gives?  Is this something new with Sierra as opposed to earlier versions?

update:  tried suggestion as per @oa and still getting the same error.

Searching `` got me this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232109/how-to-fix-bad-dd-img-write-to-sdcard.  Now, that post is about an img file that is too big for the SD.  I have a 4.1Gb img, and this is a 32Gb file, so that wouldn't apply.

But... what I've noticed is that `diskutil list` has a number of things for that disk.

```
jluc@node_modules$ diskutil list /dev/disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE         IDENTIFIER
 0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *32.1 GB    disk2
 1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    66.1 MB    disk2s1
 2:                      Linux                         32.0 GB    disk2s2
```

See how the first partition, the FAT32 boot shows @ 66.MB?

Looking some more:

```
jluc@node_modules$ df -h | egrep "disk2|Filesystem"
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
 /dev/disk2s1                        63Mi   21Mi   42Mi    33%     512          0  100%   /Volumes/boot
```

So, wondering if it's not that /dev/disk2 is not interpreted as being only 60 MB because of the boot and I am therefore getting a capacity error.  Will try to repartition it first.

Comment: What is the write speed rating of your micro SD? Some are severely constrained no matter what system or block size you choose.

Comment: Class 10.  The funny thing is... I used this exact same SD before, but using El Capitan or Yosemite (not sure what laptop I used) as the mac OS.  Ah... one additional bit of info.  The reason I have to reimage is that I (dumb me), did a `rm -rf pi3` while I had mounted the pi3 using sshfs.  So, basically, I `rm -f /` on the pi3 while running.  Noticing that, I unplugged the pi3 to stop the damage.

Comment: It cannot be "interpreted as being only 60 MB" . `dd` has no knowledge of the disk structure, and doesn't care; it just copies raw blocks. Indeed it makes no difference whether the card is formatted or not.

Comment: @Milliways.  Yeah, that's would I have expected as well.  But like I mentioned further down, I am getting formatting errors so I might have nuked the SD.  How?  I am sure an `rm -rf /` is mighty destructive, esp one interrupted midway by unplugging.  but hardware-destructive??? I will install Linux on my laptop and see if I can force it to reformat the whole SD somehow.  if that works, I'll go back to osx and `dd` - just because I want to get this working on osx.  If not, new SD.

Comment: @JLPeyret You can try formatting, but this also writes raw blocks, so is unlikely to make any difference.

Answer (score 6):

I installed the same image last night on a RPi3.

You need to unmount the disk first. Then you can write to the disk using sudo.

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/rdisk2
sudo dd bs=1m if=~/Downloads/your_image.img of=/dev/rdisk2
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

I'm on macOS Sierra, too.

Comment: Tried exactly that.  Same issue.  I know there's nothing wrong with your command.  But something is glitching either on the SD, the adapter or the Mac.

Comment: What error exactly do you get with the command above? The same 'dd: /dev/rdisk2: Input/output error'?

Comment: actually, I am getting formatting errors on the disk itself.  so i might have a corrupt SD somehow.  if that turns out to be the case, i'll remove or update this question as needed.

Comment: It most likely won't even run if still mounted. The reason this answer is correct is that it uses rdisk2 instead of disk2 - rdisk2 is the raw version as per: http://daoyuan.li/solution-dd-too-slow-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

It works for me! You may be interested the the script I use, which can copy images and compressed backups.

It includes checks to prevent you inadvertently overwriting something else and automatically unmounts the SD Card.

You need to customise the script with **disk** and **image**.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to restore backup to Pi SD card
# 2016-10-24

DSK='disk3'

# Image name (no ext)
IMG='ubuntu-standard-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi'

# Check for sensible disk
export PTYPE=$(diskutil list  /dev/$DSK | awk '/GUID_partition_scheme/ {print $2}; /Apple/ {print $2}; /Windows_NTFS/ {print $2}' )
if [ "$PTYPE" ]; then
    echo "Disk not a SD Card - Contains "$PTYPE
    exit
elif [ ! /dev/$DSK ]; then
    echo "/dev/$DSK not found"
    exit
fi

echo Ensure SD partitions are unmounted!
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/$DSK

# Check if image exists - else try to uncompress
if [ -s $IMG.img ]; then
echo $IMG.img exists
elif [ -s $IMG.img.gz ]; then
echo Uncompressing $IMG.img.gz
echo Ctl+T to show progress!
time  gunzip -k $IMG.img.gz
fi

echo please wait - This takes some time
echo Ctl+T to show progress!
time sudo dd if=$IMG.img of=/dev/r$DSK bs=1m

exit
```

Comment: What speeds do you get with this script and how does it compare with the theoretical speed of the SD media in question?

Comment: @bmike It takes less than 15 minutes to copy an 8GB image. I haven't actually timed it for a while. This is about 32MB/sec. There is nothing special in the script, just normal `dd`. When I did not use raw it could take many hours.

Comment: Thanks! That's on par with my experiences - 15 to 20 minutes to write systems in that range. Being specific will help people know they are seeing what others are.